# tikz positioning library using 'at'

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-positioning

Firstly, is it better to use the syntax `\node at (coord) {}'` or `\node[right=of coord] {}`? I prefer putting the position of the node outside of the `[]`, so I'm trying to use the positioning library syntax like: `\node[] at ([right]coord) {};`, is this possible?

If I wanted to use `on grid`, I believe I would get this behaviour simply with `x/y-shift`. But what would I would like to do is set an x-shift based on the nodes towards each other like positioning does when `on grid` is off.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(start) at (0,0) {Hello World};
%\node[anchor=west](end)   at ([xshift=1]start.east) {Over here!};  % I like this style of syntax, explicitly using 'at'
\node[right=of start] (end)   {Over here!};  % using positioning library
\node[draw=red] (end) at ([right]start)  {Over here!}; % can I use positioning library style in this way? the positioning is not the same as above, this node is overlayed with start
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, `at (0,0)` is a more convenient (?) form to write the option `at={(0,0)}`. You can use transformations inside a coordinate, such as `([xshift=10pt]0,0)` but `right` has no meaning as option inside a coordinate. You could probably define something though.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I am aware of that transformation, I'm just looking for a way to possibly define `right`  to use it in a similar manner

Comment: Sorry, your question to me looks as new feature request. So far, to my knowledge, TikZ not enable determining of coordinates on a such a way.

Comment: Ah, does position work because the right=of syntax just translates to a shift relative to the other node (taking into account which anchor) and sets the current node's anchor as well? Thanks @Zarko

Comment: This would reqire a new implementation of the coordinate parser. The positioning keys (like `right`) would also need to be adjusted so that they work. It might be easier to implement `AT ([right]start)`, i.e. a different keyword, that transforms `([<pos>=<dist>]<coord>)` into `\tikzset{<pos>=<dist> of <coord>}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would reqire a new implementation of the coordinate parser.
The positioning keys like `right` would also need to be adjusted so that they work with this.

It is much easier to implement `AT ([right]start)`, i.e. a different keyword, that transforms `([<pos>=<dist>]<coord>)` into `\tikzset{<pos>=<dist> of <coord>}`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makeatletter
\let\orig@tikz@@scan@fig\tikz@@scan@fig
\def\tikz@@scan@fig{\pgfutil@ifnextchar A\tikz@fig@scan@AT\orig@tikz@@scan@fig}
\def\tikz@fig@scan@AT AT#1(#2[#3]#4){%
  \pgfutil@in@{=}{#3}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@\tikzset{#3 of #4}\else\tikzset{#3=of #4}\fi
  \tikz@@scan@fig}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(start)                at (0,0)          {Hello World};
\node[right=of start] (end)                    {Over here!};
\node[draw=red]       (end) AT ([right] start) {Over here!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The is the most in spirit with what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in my comment, my first impression was, that your question is features request, which should be addressed to `tikz` package maintainer. My second impression was, that your request has not much (if any) sense.

To clarify above, below are some existing ways for nodes placements, which can be combined too:

- Nodes are placed on the path:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
N/.style = {draw, ultra thin, minimum height=4ex}
                    ]
\path   (0,0) node [N]  {Hello World}
        (4,0) node [N]  {Nodes on given position};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- Another possibilities is to arrange nodes in sequences which have:

  - constant distances between nodes (determined by `node distance`) borders, or
  - nodes placed on grid (grid's distances determined by `node distance`)
  - In both cases can be employed `chains` library.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm, 
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {draw, ultra thin, minimum height=4ex, on chain}
                    ]
\node [N]   (start) {Hello World};
\node [N]   (end)   {Nodes on \qty{2}{\mm}  distances};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 30mm, on grid,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {draw=red, ultra thin, minimum height=4ex, going right}
                    ]
\node [N]   (start) {Hello World};
\node [N]   (end)   {Nodes on \qty{30}{\mm} grid};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

At forming of sequence of nodes is not necessary to use `chains` library (it actually has sense when in sequences re large number of nodes), you can use just
positioning` syntax:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm, 
     N/.style = {draw, ultra thin, minimum height=4ex}
                    ]
\node [N]   (start) {Hello World};
\node [N, right=of start]   (end)   {Nodes on \qty{2}{\mm}  distances};  % I like this style of syntax, explicitly using 'at'
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 30mm, on grid,
     N/.style = {draw=red, ultra thin, minimum height=4ex}
                    ]
\node [N]   (start) {Hello World};
\node [N, right=of start]   (end)   {Nodes on \qty{30}{\mm} grid};  % I like this style of syntax, explicitly using 'at'
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The both MWE produces the same result,

[image]

In the cases, that you like to shift node apart from given coordinates, than you can write:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
N/.style = {draw, ultra thin, minimum height=4ex}
                    ]
\node [N, right] at (0,0)    {Hello World};
\node [N, right] at (3,0)    {Nodes on given position};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What to select from aforementioned is matter of the personal preferences and image content.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to, but you can split up the node label and positioning, like so:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(start) at (0,0) {Hello World};
\node[right=of start] (end)   {Over here!};  % using positioning library
\node[draw=red] (end2) [right=of start] {Over here!}; % this will be overlaid with "end"
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```